# When does an InputStream object gets closed in JasperReport object?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, inputstream

I am using `JRLoader.loadObject(someInputStreamObject)` in my project, but I was wondering when does this `InputStream` object gets closed, is it going to be closed automatically by the object returned by `JRLoader.loadObject()` ? or do we have to close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JasperReports is open source so you can see the source code e.g. [on Github for `JRLoader.loadObject(InputStream)` method](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/a4deda878e411c0856eb9178f686eaf071e3818f/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRLoader.java#L260). In this case the supplied `InputStream` object is not being closed by `JRLoader` so it has to be done manually.

Comment: Thanks for answering and sharing the github link too :-), One thing I am still unsure with is, is it safe to just close it after the call to ```JRLoader.loadObject(someInputStreamObject)``` or in a finally block? because the inputStream object is finally used in ```ObjectInputStream(InputStream)```  in the call hierarchy in the call of loadObject().